# WPF custom control, model as dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

Is it possible to use a model as a `DependencyProperty` of a custom control? I want to do this because I want to create a custom control which is basically a image drawer that gets a name and a list of datapoints for drawing.

Something like this:

Model:

```
public class Draw : NotificationObject
{

public Draw(string name, List<System.Drawing.PointF> data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Data = data;

    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<System.Drawing.PointF> _data;
    public List<System.Drawing.PointF> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (_data != value)
            {
                _data = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Custom Control:

```
public class MyCanvas: System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
   static void itemsChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property,
   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyCanvas searchTextBox = (MyCanvas)property;
        Console.WriteLine("got update");
        searchTextBox.Items = (Draw)args.NewValue;
    }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
   typeof(Draw),
   typeof(MyCanvas),new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(itemsChangedCallBack)));

    public Draw Items
    {
        get { return (Draw)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And of course the XAML:

```
<myClass:MyCanvas x:Name="Canvas1" Items="{Binding drawModel,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SizX="1600" SizY="200" />
```

And the ViewModel call:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {

   public Draw drawModel { get; set; }

   public MainWindowViewModel()
       {
           drawModel = new Draw("first", null); // custom control is notified
       }

   private someFunction() //within another thread but should not matter
       {
           drawModel.Data = newData; // custom control should be notified but is not
       }
}
```

My problem is that if I do change the drawModel.Data (property) within the ViewModel I do not get a notification to the custom control. I did it before for a simple string instead of the model and it worked. It works the first time the drawModel gets initialized but not if I update the Data property later on.

Comment: Yes it is possible... do you have some problems with your code?

Comment: yes it is possible and your code seems fine..only the typeof(DPFCanvas) should be typeof(MyCanvas)

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your model class if you want updates to be reflected in your bindings.

Comment: I'm using the NotificationObject. I have now added this to the post because I omitted it before because I thought it is obvious, otherwise I would never get any notification. Any idea?

Comment: The question is still open. Could someone help me please figure out why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works the first time the drawModel gets initialized but not if I update the Data property later on.

You should make `Data` an `ObservableCollection<PointF>` (or, even better, `ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point>`, as WPF's [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx) already supports floating point values).

The issue is that adding to, removing from, or changing a `List<T>` doesn't provide any form of notication to WPF that things have changed.  `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which is the collection version of `INotifyPropertyChagned`.

Note that this will still not trigger an update within your control.  If you require that, you could subscribe to the `Draw.Data`'s `CollectionChanged` event to be notified of changes wtihin the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model doesn't implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged`, For the first time your setting the property drawModel, in the constructor, which will be called before the UI is created completely and once UI is created, and when it is loaded it will load the current value of the property, but when you change the value again then you have to notify the UI that the value of particular property is changed.

If you have changed the values of any of the properties in the class Draw it could have been reflected since that implements `INotifiyPropertyChanged`, but your changing the value of drawModel which is in view-model and this doesn;t implement INotifiyPropertyChanged hence it doesn't update

Comment: The NotificationObject is implemented via the BaseViewModel. Sorry I added more code now. As I told, everything gets the notification, only the custom control does receive it only once. Do I need to implement the NotificationObject/INotifiyPropertyChanged also in the custom control?

Comment: Does your BaseViewModel impements INotifiyPropertyChanged?, if so then call RaisePropertyChanged in setter of drawModel setter. If your BaseViewModel  doesnt implement  INotifiyPropertyChanged, the implement it in MainWindowViewModel

Comment: The Model and the MainViewModel have the INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. If I change the drawModel.Data property I can see changes in the MainViewModel and the View. The Custom Control does not get notified. Should I provide source code?

Comment: Your Data is of type List, instead of list change that to observablecollection, because List doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged  where as observablecollection implements

Comment: When you change the value of Data you get the notification in Class Draw not in Custom control because Data is property of Draw not custom control

Comment: Also the Change of the Name does fire a notification. Kumareshan, here is the Project. https://mega.co.nz/#!jlxVhJjS!cl3moBvqh7yVFTmA-ElfqhrUYIIcT20v0oflQ40Y7CI It seems that you have a very good knowledge, so it should be easy for you to find the Problem immediatly. I basically want to get notified in the custom control when the model gets modified within the viewmodel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39857/discussion-between-user2799180-and-kumareshan)

Comment: I looked into your code, the code is partial, i could not find the complete code. That's fine that doesn't matter.

Comment: Your changing the value of the Property Data, which is present in Draw,so you'll get the notification in Draw class,not in your custom control class,if you want your custom control class to get notified,then expose a delegate in your Draw class and when ever you get notification in your Draw class invoke that delegate. In your custom control class hook to the delegate that is exposed in your Draw class. If you don't understand please let me know,i'll try provide to an example for you.

Comment: Hey Kumareshan, thanks for looking into my code. I have removed not necessary parts to make things easier for you. I still do not understand it. It would be great if you could provide me an example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Kumareshan, unfortunately this download website does not work. Says loading all the time. Maybe you could upload it somewhere else? Thanks